# WPF tooltip not scaling first time on secondary monitor, monitors differ in scaling settings

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I have 2 monitors on my Windows 10 laptop

- Monitor 1 (Main) - 1920x1080 (100% Scale) , Laptop Monitor (Intel UHD)
- Monitor 2 (Secondary) - 1920x1080 (125% Scale), External Monitor (NVIDIA)

To reproduce issue:

1. I launch program on Monitor 1, do nothing
2. Move program to Monitor 2
3. Hover unto tooltip <-- Not proper scaling (problem)
   [image]
4. Hover again unto tooltip, now correct scaling <-- OK
   [image]

GIF in action below:

[image]

***What could be causing this issue? Any help would be appreciated***

Here is the style XAML code of my Button with Tooltip

```xml
<Style x:Key="informationButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,3,-20,0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Help" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="14" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#969696"  />
    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="10000" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True" >
                    <Ellipse x:Name="buttonBackground" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background }"  />
                    <Ellipse x:Name="buttonMask" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" Fill="White"  Opacity="0" />
                    <Path x:Name="pathQuestion" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="8" Width="4" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Center" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                    Data="M2.4902344,11.761328 C2.6660156,11.761328 2.8183594,11.825781 2.9472656,11.954687 C3.0761716,12.075781 3.1406248,12.228125 3.140625,12.411718 C3.1406248,12.591406 3.0761716,12.74375 2.9472656,12.86875 C2.8144531,12.99375 2.6621094,13.05625 2.4902344,13.05625 C2.3183594,13.05625 2.1660156,12.99375 2.0332031,12.86875 C1.9042968,12.74375 1.8398436,12.591406 1.8398438,12.411718 C1.8398436,12.228125 1.9042968,12.075781 2.0332031,11.954687 C2.1621094,11.825781 2.3144531,11.761328 2.4902344,11.761328 z M2.625,4.4078121 C2.9218748,4.4078121 3.2011716,4.4468746 3.4628906,4.5249996 C3.7246091,4.6031246 3.9541013,4.7193356 4.1513672,4.8736324 C4.3486328,5.0279298 4.5039063,5.2203126 4.6171875,5.4507809 C4.7304688,5.6812501 4.7871094,5.9488282 4.7871094,6.2535152 C4.7871094,6.5425782 4.7363281,6.8003907 4.6347656,7.0269527 C4.5332031,7.2535152 4.4052734,7.4615231 4.2509766,7.6509762 C4.0966797,7.8404293 3.9296873,8.0171871 3.75,8.1812496 C3.5703123,8.3453121 3.4033201,8.5083981 3.2490234,8.6705074 C3.0947263,8.8326168 2.9667966,9.0015621 2.8652344,9.1773434 C2.7636719,9.3531246 2.7128906,9.546484 2.7128906,9.7574215 C2.7128906,9.937109 2.734375,10.100195 2.7773438,10.246679 C2.8203125,10.393164 2.8632813,10.517187 2.90625,10.61875 L1.9628906,10.61875 C1.9277343,10.517187 1.8964843,10.385351 1.8691406,10.223242 C1.8417968,10.061132 1.8281249,9.8999996 1.828125,9.7398434 C1.8281249,9.4898434 1.8779296,9.2642574 1.9775391,9.0630856 C2.0771484,8.8619137 2.2011719,8.6734371 2.3496094,8.4976559 C2.4980469,8.3218746 2.6601563,8.1529293 2.8359375,7.9908199 C3.0117185,7.8287106 3.1738279,7.6646481 3.3222656,7.4986324 C3.4707029,7.3326168 3.5947263,7.1587887 3.6943359,6.9771481 C3.7939451,6.7955079 3.8437498,6.5953126 3.84375,6.3765621 C3.8437498,6.1890626 3.8076169,6.023047 3.7353516,5.8785152 C3.6630857,5.7339845 3.5644529,5.6128907 3.4394531,5.515234 C3.3144529,5.4175782 3.1699216,5.344336 3.0058594,5.2955074 C2.8417969,5.2466798 2.6679688,5.2222657 2.484375,5.2222652 C1.8242188,5.2222657 1.2519531,5.4820313 0.76757807,6.0015621 L0.76757807,4.9703121 C1.3652343,4.5953121 1.9843749,4.4078121 2.625,4.4078121 z" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter  TargetName="buttonMask"  Property="Opacity" Value="0.1"/>
                        <Setter  TargetName="buttonMask"  Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter  TargetName="pathQuestion"  Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter  TargetName="buttonMask"  Property="Opacity" Value="0.1"/>
                        <Setter  TargetName="buttonMask"  Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
                        <Setter  TargetName="pathQuestion"  Property="Fill" Value="Black"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="buttonMask" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0.3" Duration="00:00:00.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>

                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="buttonMask" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="0" Duration="00:00:00.2" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.3"/>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsCancel" Value="False"/>
                    <Trigger Property="IsDefault" Value="False"/>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToolTip}}" TargetType="ToolTip">
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="320" />
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
            <Setter Property="Placement" Value="Right" />
            <Setter Property="ToolTipService.VerticalOffset" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="HasDropShadow" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                        <Border
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            Margin="0,0,0,30"
                            Background="#000000"
                            BorderBrush="#cccccc"
                            BorderThickness="1">
                            <ContentPresenter
                                Margin="15,10,15,10"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Placement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Right">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.HorizontalOffset" Value="-4" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Placement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="Left">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.HorizontalOffset" Value="4" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Here is the XAML that uses this style

```xml
<Button
    Width="14"
    Height="14"
    Style="{StaticResource informationButton}">
    <Button.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="This tooltip should adjust its size correctly when it is moved to a monitor with a different scaling size." />
    </Button.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

Comment: I tried but could not reproduce it with my monitor of 100% and that of 125%. I had to change the visibility of the Button to make it visible though.

Comment: I made some updates to the code to make it easy to replicate, but unfortunately, I am unable to reproduce the issue in isolation. The problem seems to occur only in my application, which I cannot share. Therefore, I am still exploring possible solutions to resolve the issue

Comment: WPF and graphics can be incredibly odd. On my dev PC I have one monitor that is technically 4k, all others are 1080p. Ran into severe issues with sizing and graphics when the application changed monitors through dragging. Only until I matched scaling and resolution exactly did the issues go away. One thing I tried, `Console.Writeline`s when a UI element is displayed and print all its actual values (font size, widths, etc.). If they are technically correct, it could be weird windows issues. I dont envy you, solving these are finicky and tough.